# incomplete definition of type struct & forward declaration of 'struct ElementoDiLista

Tags: c, declaration, typedef, incomplete-type

When I try to compile this small snippet of code I get the following errors:

```
./main.c:25:8: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct ElementoDiLista'
  lista->info=10;
  ~~~~~^
./main.c:12:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct ElementoDiLista'
typedef struct ElementoDiLista* ListaDiElementi;
```

advice please ....

the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

struct elemento 
{
int info;
struct elemento* next;
};

typedef struct elemento ElementoDiLista;
typedef struct ElementoDiLista* ListaDiElementi;


int main(void) {
  
  
  ElementoDiLista elem;
  elem.info=10;
  elem.next=NULL;
  ListaDiElementi lista;
  
  
  lista=malloc(sizeof(ElementoDiLista));
  lista->info=10;
  
 
  
  return 0;
}

I expect that my code works since come from a book.
```

Comment: `ElementoDiLista` isn't a `struct`, it's a typedef. So, `typedef ElementoDiLista`, not `typedef struct ElementoDiLista`.

Comment: You need to use either `struct elemento` or `ElementoDiLista` in the second `typedef`.  You can't use `struct ElementoDiLista` since `ElementoDiLista` is a type name, not a structure tag.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have complete type `struct ElementoDiLista`. You have complete type `struct elemento` and its alias `ElementoDiLista`.

```
struct elemento 
{
int info;
struct elemento* next;
};

typedef struct elemento ElementoDiLista;
```

So instead of this typedef definition

```
typedef struct ElementoDiLista* ListaDiElementi;
```

you have to write

```
typedef ElementoDiLista* ListaDiElementi;
```

The compiler issues an error because in this typedef definition

```
typedef struct ElementoDiLista* ListaDiElementi;
```

you introduced a new type specifier `struct ElementoDiLista` that is an incomplete type and has nothing common with `struct elemento` nor with its alias `ElementoDiLista`.